# Direct store and taking ID from server response while add action

Tags: javascript, extjs

There is the store with direct proxy. I want to create new record. Direct proxy sends it to server and recieve sended data width **NEW ID**. I want to insert this **ID** in the grid, but...

Added record shows for a moment and then It become nulled (all field are null). I see null id and nothing more. How to update that record (or do any action) to see it in the grid correctly with new id?

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to anything special to insert record to the grid. The way ExtJs base store/proxy classes work is this - when store send update to the remote server it will try to parse new records from the response. And it should automatically replace existing records in your store object (which to this moment will already have new record, but without Id and with phantom = true).

So you need to make sure that response you're receiving from the server does contain new record and that your proxy is configured properly to parse it from the response.

Comment: Here is my returning json {"action":"Api","method":"create","type":"rpc","tid":5,"result":{"success":true,"data":{"ID_CLIENT_GROUP":14,"ID_DEPARTMENT":89,"NAME":"cxz"}}}.
 I need to read **bold**result.data**bold**. I changed root propery of proxy reader. If root is "", then it's creating nulled record. If I change it to "result" or "result.data" it's adding record without ID in record, but with other fields...

Comment: But when I set root to data it works. My problem was in parsing in Api class. Thanks.. You have helped me with that problem:)